# Custom Generic GetTable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

For a DataContext I'm working on, I don't want to load the Tables untill their needed.
I want to make a little method that would check if a certain Table is loaded before loading it, but I end up having n Methods doing the same thing :

```
private void Load(ref Table<Order> Orders)
{
    if (Orders == null)
        Orders = this.GetTable<Order>();
}
```

I'm trying to make a generic one for obvious reasons, but I get a "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Linq.Table'" exception while doing this :

```
private void Load<T>(ref Table<T> TableToLoad)
{
    if (TableToLoad == null)
        TableToLoad = this.GetTable<T>();
}
```

Comment: you do know that Linq2Sql doesn't actually load any data when you access GetTable<T> right? You must run a query and then do a ToArray() or something like that for the query to actually run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add '`where T: class`' to your method.

Comment: Thanks! Quite simple, yet so important.